# How to add the Python nature to a project imported from GitHub?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I just imported a GitHub repository as a new project into Eclipse. Most of the code is Python and I have PyDev installed. When I try to configure a run the Main time always yields this message in the PYTHONPATH area: "Project should have a Python nature". The *Run* button remains greyed out no matter what.

Assessing the *Project Natures* tab in *Project Properties* dialogue I have no option to add a Python nature.

How can run I this project? Thank you.

**Update**: The contents of the `.project` file are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>PyWPS</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.python.pydev.PyDevBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.python.pydev.pythonNature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

And the `.pydevproject` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>PyWPS</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.python.pydev.PyDevBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.python.pydev.pythonNature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a nature manually you can edit the `.project` file and add:

```xml
<natures>
    <nature>org.python.pydev.pythonNature</nature>
</natures>
```

(if there is already a `<natures>` entry add the `<nature>` line to that).

The [pydev FAQ](http://pydev.org/faq.html) section `How do I import existing projects/sources into PyDev?` covers other files you might need.

Comment: I already have that line in the `.project` file (see the edit to the question), this problem must be related to something else.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it actually works with Eclipse Neon.

Comment: Adding natures to the .project file is dangerous. See my answer.